# Условие в игре на ничью

Tags: delphi

Есть условие в игре X_0:

```
  if (a[1]=gmr1) and (a[2]=gmr1) and (a[3]=gmr1) then pobed:=1;
  if (a[4]=gmr1) and (a[5]=gmr1) and (a[6]=gmr1) then pobed:=1;
  if (a[7]=gmr1) and (a[8]=gmr1) and (a[9]=gmr1) then pobed:=1;
  if (a[1]=gmr1) and (a[5]=gmr1) and (a[9]=gmr1) then pobed:=1; 
  if (a[3]=gmr1) and (a[5]=gmr1) and (a[7]=gmr1) then pobed:=1;
```

Сравнение ячеек. `gmr1 = gamer1`. Как сделать условие ничьи?
a[] - массив хранит ячейки. 
gmr1 - игрок 1. 
Условие ничьи - нет совпадающих комбинаций 3x ( т.е. трех одинаковых ячеек - вертикаль, диагональ, горизонталь )
При такой расстановке, сразу выходит: Ничья.

```
if (pobed=0) and (a[1]<>gmr1) and (a[2]<>gmr1) and (a[3]<>gmr1) and (a[4]<>gmr1) and (a[5]<>gmr1) and (a[8]<>gmr1) and (a[7]<>gmr1) and (a[8]<>gmr1) and (a[9]<>gmr1) and (a[1]<>gmr1) and (a[5]<>gmr1) and (a[9]<>gmr1) and (a[3]<>gmr1) and (a[5]<>gmr1) and (a[7]<>gmr1) then pobed:=3; // ничья
```

Comment: И когда уже люди научатся нормально формулировать свои вопросы?..

Что за игра? Что хранит переменная `gmr1`? Что хранит массив `a[]`? И, собственно, каким должно быть условие ничьи?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pobed:=-1; // неопределённый результат
// ищем условие победы gmr1 - pobed=1
// ищем условие победы gmr2 - pobed=2
if (pobed=-1) and (a[1]<>empty) and (a[2]<>empty) and (a[3]<>empty) and ... and (a[9]<>empty) then pobed:=0; // ничья
```

empty - пустая ячейка